# PHP Warning with Custom Fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, metabox

For the love of God can anyone help me?

My theme I had built a year or so ago, I added custom meta boxes/fields. I have created numerous custom taxonomies. But I didn't want the custom taxonomies to be placed in traditional check boxes. I want them in SELECT dropdown menus as options. Everything worked fine until I updated from version 4.9 to 5.2(latest update).

Now, when I try to add a new listing/post, it does not save the data and throws multiple PHP warnings.

First I will display the warnings and below that will be my code.

**************** EDIT *****************

[image: php error]

Here is a link to my Github which shows the files I am working with:
https://github.com/pcross1986/car-dealership

**UPDATE - 6-28-2019
SCREENSHOT with errors**

[image: Screenshot of new errors]

**UPDATE - 6-28-2019
When trying to add a new post I also get this error**

[image]

**UPDATE 6.29.2019**

It looks like I am very close. I can now go into a current post and it looks like the data is now saving after editing and updating the listing.

The problem now is, when I go to create a NEW listing, it gives me this error. Screenshot is below:

[image]

Comment: That's far too much code to review for one question, and I can't format it properly for you without exceeding the allowed number of characters. Can you reduce it in some way? The code for registering the post type shouldn't be relevant when dealing with meta boxes, for example.

Comment: I apologize for the mess..... I have uploaded the files to my Github so is much easier to read. I have also updated the screenshot above.

https://github.com/pcross1986/car-dealership

Answer (score 0):

**Update 29.6.19**

I think the `array_map()` error is actually caused by how the selects are named. They have names like `tax_input[fuel-type]`, which probably results in them getting passed to the default taxonomy saving function. As only single value is passed for each select and I assume the tax save handler expects an array, the `array_map()` warning is raised.

This would also explain why some of the values weren't saved. The values weren't in `$_POST[$valid_taxonomy]`, but `$_POST['tax_input'][$valid_taxonomy]` (*meta_boxes.php:416*). I missed this when I wrote my loop examples.

You could experiment with either changing the select names to `name="tax_slug"` or by changing the names to array format `name="tax_input[fuel-type][]"`. `foreach ( $valid_taxonomies as $valid_taxonomy )` should start working with the former option and would be unnecessary with the latter.

Try replacing *meta_boxes.php lines 59-60* with `wp_nonce_field( 'save_car_details_meta', 'nonce_car_details');` and *lines 361-363* with `check_admin_referer( 'save_car_details_meta', 'nonce_car_details' );`. Do similiar thing for the testimonials metabox and its saving function.

---

**New answer**

I had a quick glance on your code on GitHub and I think something like this should make it work.

Replace lines 372 - 518 with the code below. Have a helper array with valid keys that you compare the `$_POST` against. Loop meta and term data separately and save them accordingly - meta data as post meta, set term data as post terms.

```
if ( 'revision' === $post->post_type ) {
  return;
};

$valid_meta_keys = array(
  '_vin',
  '_mileage',
  '_intcol',
  '_tot',
  '_nod',
  '_trim',
  '_price',
);
foreach ( $valid_meta_keys as $valid_meta_key ) {
  $current_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $valid_meta_key, FALSE );
  $new_value = isset( $_POST[$valid_meta_key] ) ? $_POST[$valid_meta_key] : '';

  if ( ! $new_value && ! $current_value ) {
    delete_post_meta($post->ID, $valid_meta_key);
    continue;
  } else if ( ! $new_value ) {
    continue;
  }

  // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
  if ( is_array( $new_value ) ) {
    $new_value = implode(',', $new_value);    
  }

  // Returns meta_id if the meta doesn't exist, otherwise returns true on success and false on failure. It also returns false if the value submitted is the same as the value that is already in the database. 
  update_post_meta($post->ID, $valid_meta_key, sanitize_text_field( $new_value ) );
}

$valid_taxonomies = array(
  'makes',
  'model_year',
  'body_type',
  'colors',
  'drivetrain',
  'transmissions',
  'fuel-type',
  'engine',  
);
foreach ( $valid_taxonomies as $valid_taxonomy ) {
  $new_value = isset( $_POST[$valid_taxonomy] ) ? intval( $_POST[$valid_taxonomy] ) : NULL;
  // Replace previous terms or clear with NULL $new_value
  wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $new_value, $valid_taxonomy, false );
}
```

Replace lines 597 - 610 with the code below. No need for a loop here as there's only one meta key.

```
$customer_name = isset( $_POST['_customer'] ) ? $_POST['_customer']: '';
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_customer', FALSE ) ) {
  update_post_meta($post->ID, '_customer', sanitize_text_field( $customer_name ) );
} else {
  delete_post_meta($post->ID, '_customer');
}
```

---

**First answer**

<strike>As Jacob Peattie pointed out in his comment, your question has quite a lot of code, which makes it rather difficult to review.</strike>

But based on the screenshots you've provided, you should dig into the theme files noted on the PHP warnings and add some guard clauses to the related lines. Here are some general examples,

> Undefined index

```
// key is set in array and the value is not empty
if ( ! empty( $array['some_key'] ) ) {
  // some code
}
```

or

```
// key is set in array, but value can be empty
if ( isset( $array['some_key'] ) ) {
  // some code
}
```

> argument should be an array or invalid argument supplied for foreach

```
// make sure the variable is array
if ( is_array( $something ) ) {
  // foreach loops
  // array_maps
}
```

> undefined variable

```
// variable exists and is different than NULL
if ( isset( $variable ) ) {
  // some code
}
```

or

```
// variable exists and value equals FALSE
if ( ! empty( $variable ) ) {
  // some code
}
```

Do add fallbacks for `if`s with `else`s, if needed. E.g.

- add key to array with empty or some default value
- set variable
- cast variable to array

Comment: `empty` includes and `isset` check already. :)

Comment: @fuxia Yes, that is true. I improved the formatting of my answer to make it more clear that the examples are different cases.

Comment: I apologize for the mess, I have updated the screenshot above. And here is my Github where the files are that I am working with. Should be much easier to read now.

https://github.com/pcross1986/car-dealership

Comment: @Preston, thank you for moving the code to GitHub. I had a look at the metabox code and added new code examples to my answer. The warnings were caused by not having any `isset()` or `empty()` checks on the code. Also there was a mixture of post and term meta functions on the metabox saving function, which caused the undefined variable errors. In my answe I've separated the post meta saving and term setting into two different loops.

Comment: It looks like you are getting somewhere. After saving the new code, most of those errors went away, however it is still not saving data, and throws some errors now. I have updated a new screenshot above for the new errors showing after updating a  listing/post.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen I also updated the code on my Github meta_boxes.php file

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen I also just discovered other error when creating an entire NEW listing/post. The other errors populate when I tried to save a post that was already created.... But the last screenshot errors is when creating a new post from the beginning.

Comment: @Preston I updated my answer, please have a look at it.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen It looks like I am close. However there is a little error happening when I go to create a NEW post/listing. Screenshot and update is posted above.

NOTE:

I tried refreshing page but nothing changes, still the same error. Also, Im sure this doesn't matter, but I currently have the Testimonial meta box section commented out since I am focusing on these meta boxes for listings. The code on my Github account has been updated so you can review my code.
https://github.com/pcross1986/car-dealership/blob/master/meta_boxes.php

Comment: @Preston That new WP error notice is an nonce issue probably. If you comment out the newly added `check_admin_referer()` from the metabox save function, you can check if that is causing the error. If that is the case, then either have a look at the nonce documentation to perhaps find alternative solution or ask a new question regarding it. Unfortunately at the moment I can't spot what could be wrong with the new nonce field and check.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen Thank you so much for your help. I commented that line out and now it works. I am guessing I need to address this issue still, seeing how it would be a security issue? I know php fairly well but obviously not as well as you do. I do not know too much about  what "nonce" is and how it works. According to Wordpress documentation, you have implemented the nonce correctly, so I will have to do some more digging into why it fails with the check_admin_referer().

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen I found the problem! Using the save_post hook was causing the issue. Changing it to the post_updated hook fixed the problem........... add_action('post_updated', 'wpt_save_details_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen ......... but of course I found another problem. Could be small to you hahahaha.... But if you don't mind taking a look at my new question, I have posted it here. Your help is greatly appreciated. Maybe I can buy you lunch??
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341865/custom-meta-boxes-nonce-issue-move-to-trash-issue

Comment: @Preston, no worries. This is just a fun pasttime for me to help people here on WPSE. If you find my answers helpful, you can mark them as accepted and click the upvote, and I'm happy with that.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen I do vote up, but says my reputation points are low. I guess because I am new to the site.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen Any chance you can help me with this one? I would think you could solve this one fairly easy https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342126/trouble-adding-custom-featured-image-for-custom-taxonomy-terms