# Trouble adding custom featured image for custom taxonomy TERMS

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, post-thumbnails, terms

**Wordpress version 5.2.2**

**Local development - WAMP**

**PHP version 7.0.1**

I am building car dealership website.

**Goal:**

Set featured image for custom taxonomy - Body Types

Set featured image for custom taxonomy - Makes

**Problem / Issue:**
The Body Types image is working as expected, but the Makes image will **NOT** add or "set". I tried copying / duplicating the code for Body Types and replacing variables where needed to get the same functionality for Makes, but something must be duplicated incorrectly. I say this because when I remove the Body Types code, the Makes code works and I can add an image. But of course I need both taxonomies to function correctly. I was wondering if anyone can spot the problem so that both work correctly.

I will post screenshots below to describe what I am trying to do.

My code can be seen here in the file custom-taxonomies.php on my Github account: https://github.com/pcross1986/car-dealership/blob/master/custom-taxonomies.php

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is due to script conflict so please change "Add Image" button id and class for both taxonomy.

I have tried this and it is working fine at my end.

Comment: @Bhupen I love You!!!

Comment: Preston... Good to hear that my solution worked.